# Отключите детерминизм для этой компиляции

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Хочу сделать что бы версия сборки менялась автоматически в файле AssemblyInfo.cs прям дан пример

```
 // Можно задать все значения или принять номер сборки и номер редакции по умолчанию.
// используя "*", как показано ниже:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Но если мы меняем строку 1.0.0.0 на 1.0.* выдает ошибку :
Ошибка  CS8357  Указанная строка версии содержит подстановочные знаки, несовместимые с детерминизмом. Удалите их из строки версии либо отключите детерминизм для этой компиляции. Что делать?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. А если менять не напрямую в AssemblyInfo.cs, а через свойства проекта?

Comment: @АндрейNOP сразу выдает ошибку Строка не является действительным значением для версии.

Comment: Это после чего?

Comment: @АндрейNOP если в свойствах проекта меняешь вылетает окошко с ошибкой

Answer (score 3):

Нужно в файле проекта .csproj заменить значение параметра
 `<Deterministic>...</Deterministic>` с `true` на `false`.